# Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, oracle

I am not sure how to resolve this error.

I have a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public OracleDecimal ID { get; set; }
    public string FIELD1 { get; set; }
    public string FIELD2 { get; set; }
    public OracleDate FIELD3 { get; set; }
}
```

I built a List then make a call to the SP.

```
        OracleParameter p_ID = new OracleParameter("p_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, records.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
        OracleParameter p_FIELD1 = new OracleParameter("p_FIELD1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, records.Select(x => x.FIELD1).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
        OracleParameter p_FIELD2 = new OracleParameter("p_FIELD2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, records.Select(x => x.FIELD2).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
        OracleParameter p_FIELD3 = new OracleParameter("p_FIELD3", OracleDbType.Date, records.Select(x => x.FIELD3).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);

        var result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("BEGIN MY_PACKAGE.MY_PROC(:p_ID, :p_FIELD1, :p_FIELD2, :p_FIELD3); END;", p_ID, p_FIELD1, p_FIELD2, p_FIELD3);
```

However I get the error
Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

When I create my list I have the following:

```
OracleDate myDate = new OracleDate(DateTime.Now);
var myRecord = new MyClass
                        {
                            ID = ((OracleDecimal)ID).Value,
                            FIELD1 = field1,
                            FIELD2 = field2,
                            FIELD3 = myDate
                        };
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`records.Select(x => ...)` will return a list of values, not a single value.

You should wrap your code around a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
    OracleParameter p_ID = new OracleParameter("p_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, record.Id, ParameterDirection.Input);
    OracleParameter p_FIELD1 = new OracleParameter("p_FIELD1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, record.FIELD1, ParameterDirection.Input);
    OracleParameter p_FIELD2 = new OracleParameter("p_FIELD2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, records.FIELD2, ParameterDirection.Input);
    OracleParameter p_FIELD3 = new OracleParameter("p_FIELD3", OracleDbType.Date, records.FIELD3, ParameterDirection.Input);

    var result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("BEGIN MY_PACKAGE.MY_PROC(:p_ID, :p_FIELD1, :p_FIELD2, :p_FIELD3); END;", p_ID, p_FIELD1, p_FIELD2, p_FIELD3);
}
```

Comment: In this case it will call the stored proc x amount of times.  I am trying to pass an array of data to the proc so that the proc is only called once.

Comment: @JDS Then you should update your procedure signature. As it is now, your procedure can only take a single values as a arguments, not a list of them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.    I changed the signature and I can now call the SP once and insert 3000 records in 0.24 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter construction code is supplying an array as the value of the parameter. Consider this line:

```
OracleParameter p_ID = new OracleParameter("p_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal, records.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
```

The call to `ToArray()` immediately takes the result - even if there is only one - and turns it into an array. That's dissimilar from the parameter type, and thus the attempt to perform a conversion fails. If you are sure you'll return only a single record, provide an array index to the call.

Comment: Would that be the same as doing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal[] ID = records.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();